# PDO lastInsertId()

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using PDO on a MySQL database and try to retrive `lastInsertId()`.

I thought I was going to get the last inserted vlue in column `id` in my table which is my `primary_key`. However, all I get is `0` as output

```
        $statement = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM MY_TABLE";
        $sql = $dbh->query($statement);
        $lastId = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $lastId = $lastId[0];
        return $lastId;
```

Comment: Just to make sure, have you inserted something with this connection before running this code? Also, is this a transaction?

Comment: last_insert_id() only has a value if you actually did an insert USING THIS CONNECTION. it won't return the last used ID in the table, it won't give you an id from a connection 10 requests back.

Comment: P.S. It's just `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`  There's no `FROM` clause.

Comment: This is in a method called ´getLastID´ its called right after an insert method. First ´$db->query($sql);´ second ´$db->getLastID();´

Comment: Take a look at [pdo.lastinsertid](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Probably what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

`PDO` class has a method called `lastInsertId()`. You can use the method after inserting record/records to collect last insert id.

Comment: Just tried it. But I dont understand the value I get, what can I do with it?

Comment: First insert record in database and run `echo $dbh->lastInsertId(); ` immediately after it. Like this example:

`$dbh->query('INSERT INTO users SET email="asdadlj@sdfdsf.com"');


echo $dbh->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Yes, but the value I get is not something I do have stored in my table. I thought the output would be something like last inserted primary key.

Comment: Ie, the value I get when `echo` is `112113`. That number does not relate to anything for my second insert statement. In my case I want to get my primary key, `id` to be used and saved in my second insert statement as `event_id`

Comment: @Andreas can you please post you code. That you are running now.

Comment: `$sql = $dbh->prepare($statement);
            $sql->execute();
   $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
   return $lastId;`

Comment: Found the problem. So its working now. But is it possible to create a method like "getLastestId" which I can call just to get it anywhere?

Comment: @Andreas what is your last insert id in database?

Comment: @Andreas Sure, it is possible.

Comment: @Andreas extend pdo class and use `lastInsertId()` method as you want.

Comment: Would like something like this: `public function getLastID(){
    $dbh = $this->db_connect();     
    if($dbh){
        try{
   $lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
   return $lastId;
        }
        catch(PDOException $err){
            return $err->getMessage();
        }
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}`